# FATAL: Cannot Initialize ActiveBar (actbar.ocx might not be registered)

Tags: vb6

I opened my existing vb6 project in win7, and when i tried to compile and run it, this is the error: 
FATAL: Cannot Initialize ActiveBar (actbar.ocx might not be registered)

Anybody who ever encountered this error before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to buy a copy. Now you also know why not to use obscure components in your programing, makes it difficult to recompile 19 years later.

This mob might be able to help you

http://www.componentsource.com/products/activebar/index.html